# C++ OpenGL Window and Context creation framework / library

Tags: c++, opengl, window, multiplatform

I'm searching for an multi platform OpenGL framework that abstracts the creation of windows and gl contexts in C++.
I'd like to have an OO representation of Window, Context & co where i can instantiate a Window, create a Context and maybe later set the window to fullscreen.

I'm thinking about implementing this myself for xgl, wgl and agl. But before

So here comes the Question:

Which libraries / frameworks should i check out first, before inventing the wheel again?

**Edit:**
So far named libraries:

- [glut](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/)
- [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/)
- [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)
- [gtkglext](http://gtkglext.sourceforge.net/index)
- [wxwdigets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)
- [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)

Comment: I'm using GLUT and wxWidgets successfully in two separate projects. The only downside to GLUT under Win32 is that it opens up a DOS window - good for seeing any printf's, but it doesn't look as professional to have an app that opens up that window.

Comment: @Jim: That's a bit in the executable that can easily be changed with `editbin`, and is usually an artefact of compilation flags?

Comment: Hmm, could be, I would be curious if it were that simple. In my case, it's just a Win32 reference build for a console game, so I hadn't looked into it too deeply. Plus for debugging purposes, I actually like/need to see the printfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SMFL](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) is another, similar to [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), but takes a more object oriented approach.

Comment: This one sounds promising ( their site says: SFML is composed of several packages to perfectly suit your needs. You can use SFML as a minimal windowing system to interface with OpenGL, or as a fully-featured multimedia library for building games or interactive programs. ).

Comment: I'm going to implement it myself - but since i think i can reuse some of the SMFL code i will accept this answer

Comment: SFML is lovely. It doesn't (or maybe didn't) support creating contexts with stencil buffers, but hey you can edit the code.

Answer (score 6):

You could look at [Glut](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) (C), [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) (C++), [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) (C).

Comment: I have already worked with glut (it was nice for the little opengl examples back at university but i think it wont fit in a bigger project).
The Qt api seems nice - but i don't like the thought to introduce a dependecy to Qt. It seems to heavyweight for my needs. The same goes for SDL.

Comment: @Christoph: I can fully understand what you mean. In an inhouse solution for a former employer I had to solve a similar problem. First attempts were using the platform bindings I mentioned above. After a year or so I switched to your idea of implementing platform specifics myself.

Answer (score 3):

[wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) is another alternative, but may also be too heavyweight.

Answer (score 0):

[libapril](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libapril/) is nice also. It is clean, simple and supports newer mobile platforms.